# PieCloudDB Database's storage formats

Tags: format, storage

In addition to object storage, does PieCloudDB database support any other storage options?

Answer (score 0):

PieCloudDB database currently supports object storage, NAS, HDFS, etc. It is recommended to use object storage to fully leverage the performance improvement brought by the separation of storage and computation. PieCloudDB utilizes its in-house developed storage engine called "JANM" which uses a hybrid row-column storage approach. The data is stored in object storage, with each block size defaulting to 16MB. Users can customize the block size according to their needs.